# WPF Design: How to make User control with rounded corner and shadow effect

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

We want to make the UI control exactly as mentioned in the image. It is rounded corner, like shadow effect and thin while color line around the box. The size of the control shall be size of the parent. We tried using example, nothing matches this design given by design team.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the DropShadowEffect.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Background="LightGray">
        <Border Margin="4"
                BorderBrush="White"
                Background="LightGray"
                BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
                CornerRadius="8,8,8,8">
            <TextBlock Margin="10"
                        Text="Hello, world!"
                        FontSize="24"
                        FontWeight="Bold" />
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="Gray" Opacity="0.5" />
            </Border.Effect>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's one way to accomplish the effect:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Background="LightGray">
        <Rectangle Margin="10,10,0,0" Fill="DarkGray" RadiusX="8" RadiusY="8"/>
        <Border Margin="4" BorderBrush="White" Background="LightGray" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="8,8,8,8">
            <TextBlock Margin="10" Text="Hello, world!" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I've made the colors darker and the roundedness larger so it's easier to see for the demo:

[image: Rounded with Shadow]

This scales to the available space and content goes inside the border.

Comment: thats an amazing example.  The selected answer was too simplified and didnt work for.  Setting the correct margins are still important or the usercontrol wont have round corners. Your example here is exact though.